# Elastic Search query match on keyword 'OR'

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.0

Given the mapping:

```
{
  "searchquestion": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "server": {
          "properties": {
            "hostname": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have put the following documents into this index:

```
{
   "server": {
       "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
   }      
}
{
   "server": {
       "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
   }      
}
{
   "server": {
       "hostname": "server1-linux.loc1.uk"
   }      
}
```

I would like to query the exact text of the `hostname`. Luckily, this can be done because there is an additional keyword type field on this field.

Successful query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "server.hostname.keyword": {
              "query": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like to extend this query string, to include another hostname to search for. In my results, I expect to have both documents returned.

My attempt:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "server.hostname.keyword": {
              "query": "server1-windows.loc2.uk server1-linux.loc1.uk",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns no hits, I suspect because the default analyser is splitting this query up into sections, but I'm actually searching the keyword field which is a full string. I cannot add `analyzer: keyword` to this query search, as `server1-windows.loc2.uk server1-linux.loc1.uk` as an exact string won't match anything either.

How can I search for both these strings, as their complete selves?
i.e. `"query": ["server1-windows.loc2.uk", "server1-linux.loc1.uk"]`

I would also like to use wildcards to match any `loc`. I would expect
`"query": ["server1-windows.*.uk"]` to match both windows servers, but I get no hits.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use a combination of filter and query_string, something like:
`bool: { filter: { query_string: { query: "server.hostname.keyword: (sever1 OR server2)"} } }

Comment: This results in 0 hits still.

Comment: Ahh ok, can't really test these out since I'm not working on Elastic Stack at the moment, apologies for that. Since you also want to use wildcards for server names, try something like:
`query: { terms: { server.hostname: ["loc1", "loc2"] } }` to have all the servers in response from those 2 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Query_String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to get your desired result

**Case 1:**

**Query**:

```
GET server/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(server1-windows.loc2.uk) OR (server1-linux.loc1.uk)",
      "default_field": "server.hostname.keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.9808291,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "server",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "server": {
            "hostname": "server1-linux.loc1.uk"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "server",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "server": {
            "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "server",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "server": {
            "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Case 2: with wildcard(*)**

**Query:**

```
GET server/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "server1-windows.*.uk",
      "default_field": "server.hostname.keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "server",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "server": {
            "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "server",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "server": {
            "hostname": "server1-windows.loc2.uk"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```